# Why this php query doesn't work?

Tags: php, sql-server

How to use `GetDate()` instead of `time()` and instead of `604800` check to be for 14 days like maybe: `(TransferTime < DATEADD(DAYS,-14,GETDATE())`

```
                           $count = $db->doQuery('SELECT * FROM PANEL_NT WHERE strAccountID = ?', $_SESSION['strAccountID']);
                            $row = $db->doRead();
                            if ((intval($row['nTime']) + 604800) <= time() || !$count)
                            {
                                    $db->doQuery('SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_CHAR WHERE strAccountID = ?', $_SESSION['strAccountID']);
                                    $row = $db->doRead();
                                    $db->doQuery('EXEC NT ?', $_SESSION['strAccountID']);
                                    $db->doQuery('DELETE FROM PANEL_NT WHERE strAccountID = ?', $_SESSION['strAccountID']);
                                    $db->doQuery('INSERT INTO PANEL_NT (strAccountID, nTime) VALUES (?, ?)', $_SESSION['strAccountID'], time());
```

Comment: are you certain that `PANEL_NT` has only two fields?

Comment: Yes, `varchar(21)` and `smalldatetime`

Comment: Ahh, I see. `varchar(21)` is the account id. So, I got this error. `The name "nrovaccount" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.` and also second error: `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smalldatetime`

Comment: Anyone have any clue how to edit, so there wont be errors for both values ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `smalldatetime` expects a format like this: `02/10/2010 12:30` and `time()` returns a long integer. So, either change the database to have a long integer in this field, or change your query to format a date in this way: `2010-10-02 12:30`.

Also, its often useful to explicitly state the order of the fields in the insert, in case they are defined in a different way in the table: `INSERT INTO PANEL_NT(account_id, datetime) VALUES (?, ?)`

Comment: To what I should change `smalldatetime`, so It can handle the `time()` ?

Comment: Nor `timestamp` and `datetime` doesnt work. Any other clue? Also, I get error for account id as well as you can see above.

Comment: secure in what sense?

Comment: I really need to use `GetDate()` Do you know how I can convert my script to handle it and check for 14 days? I will edit my main post now. Please look at it.

Comment: I edited my main post please check it out if you know how to edit it exactly to support `GetDate()` instead of `time()` and check if 14 days have passed already after that to execute the queries.

Comment: As my answer said - your other option would have been to format the `time()` in the way small date wants, i.e. this way: `date("Y-m-d H:i", time())`